# Generators and relations of an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples, intuition

I'm reading Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across this definition in the added picture below the line that I don't understand.

> From a previous chapter: an abelian group $G$ has generators $B$ and relations $\Delta$ iff $G \approx F/R$, where $F$ is a free abelian group with basis $B$ and $R$ is generated by $\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is a subset of $F$.

How do the relations defined below satisfy the definition defined above?  Shouldn't the relations be a subset of some $F$?  Why are they defined as a condition that seem to alter elements?  What do any of the permutation subscripts mean?

Can someone give me a simple example of a group $C_q(K)$ from the below definition?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it is standard practice to write a relation in the form $a=b$ when you mean the element $a-b$ of the free group (so $a=0$ means that $a$ is one of the relations).

For your second question, $\pi 1$ means the permutation $\pi$ applied to the number 1, so $(p_{\pi 0}, p_{\pi 1}, ..., p_{\pi q})$ may be equal to, for example, $(p_4, p_q, ..., p_3)$, if $\pi$ sends 0 to 4, 1 to $q$, $q$ to 3, etc.

For your third question, if $q=1$, then the generators are all pairs of vertices of either of the forms $(p, p)$ or $(p,q)$ if there is an edge from $p$ to $q$. The relations are of the form $(p,p)$ and $(p,q) = -(q,p)$, i.e., $(p,q)+(q,p)$. This is isomorphic to the free abelian group with generators $(p,q)$ where there is an edge from $p$ to $q$ and $p$ is less than $q$ in the ordering on the vertices given by the orientation. This description should hold in general, I think: $C_q(K)$ should be isomorphic to the free abelian group on the elements $\langle p_0, ..., p_q \rangle$ where the $p_i$'s are distinct and span a simplex.

Comment: So for $C_1(\Delta^2=[e_0, e_1, e_2])$, we should have: $$\text{Generators=}\{(e_0, e_1), (e_0, e_2), (e_1, e_2)\}$$ and $$\text{Relations}=\{(e_0, e_1)-(\text{sgn}\space\pi)(e_{\pi 0}, e_{\pi 1}), \dots, (e_1, e_2)-(\text{sgn}\space\pi)(e_{\pi 1}, e_{\pi 2}), (e_0, e_0), (e_1, e_1), (e_2, e_2)\}$$

And each $\text{sgn}(\pi)=-1$ because each permutation $\pi$ is either a permutation between $(0,1), (0,2),$ or $(1,2)$ which is always odd.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The generators should also include $(e_1, e_0)$, $(e_0, e_0)$, etc. Then yes, the relations are $(e_i, e_i)$ and $(e_i, e_j) - (e_j, e_i)$.